# Logcat filter showing everything from A, but only messages from B that starts with XYZ

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I want to create a logcat filter in eclipse, that will show me all messages from log tag A, but only messages starting with XYZ from log tag B. Is this possible, and how?